# Reading text file in QT without QFile

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having issues importing part of my project into QT creator so I can create a graphical interface for it.
Basically, my biggest issue right now is that the program will not read data from text files.

```
Repo<Tree, 10> r1;
r1.setFileName("Trees.txt");
r1.loadFromFile();
assert(r1.getSize() == 4); //this gives me an error, since it considers the size to be 0(empty)
```

This code should import my data from file Tress.txt into a container, but it doesn't do anything in QT creator(In visual studio it works perfectly).
Functions setFileName(string n) and loadFromFile() are these:

```
template <class T, int cap> void Repo<T, cap>::setFileName(string name)
{
    fileName = name;
}
```

and

```
template <class T, int cap> void Repo<T, cap>::loadFromFile()
{
    ifstream fin;
    T obj;
    fin.open(fileName);
    while (fin >> obj)
    {
        elem.push_back(obj);
        size++;
    }
}
```

What can I do about this issue? Don't tell me I have to use that QFile class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you don't *have* to use `QFile`. Had you done so, you'd have had the same problem. Qt isn't magic, it won't magically make other code not work.

You never check for any errors. If you did, you'd notice that your program fails to open the file, because you're opening file with a relative path but you failed to control the working directory of your program. You'll need to run the program in the directory where the `Trees.txt` file resides, or, better yet, provide the program with an absolute path to the file either via UI or as a command line argument.

The difference has nothing to do with Qt, but merely with the IDE you're using. Whatever was the old way you used to build and run your code would end up with the program running in the folder where the `Trees.txt` file was. That's not the case anymore. Go to the "Projects"->"Build & Run" pane in Qt Creator, select the Run tab of the current project configuration, and select the proper Working directory.

Comment: So I should just move the file to the working directory of my program? Currently, the text file resides in "C:\Users\Mihai\Documents\lab14" where all my other source/header files are as well. Where should I put it then?

Comment: Nevermind, finally figured it out. Had to write it as r1.setFileName("C:\\Users\\Mihai\\Documents\\lab14\\Pom.txt"); (Double blackslashes for some reason). Thanks for the help!

Comment: ***Double blackslashes for some reason*** Remember in `c++` the `\\` is a special character in string literals. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape